# desintegration constant

Tags: approximation

I have this system in maple and I can't get it work write:

sist:=diff(x(t), t) =-k*x(t), x(0)=x0;

Can someone help me get the desintegration constant k if the half-time is t1/2=700*10^6

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation is
$$x(t)=x_0e^{-kt}.$$

To say that the half-life is $h$ is to say that $x(h)=\frac{x_0}{2}$. Substituting in the formula for $x(t)$, we get
$$x_0e^{-kh}=\frac{x_0}{2}.$$

Cancel the $x_0$, and take reciprocals (this part is not strictly necessary).
We get 
$$e^{kh}=2.$$
Take the natural logarithm, which we will call $\ln$.
We get 
$$kh=\ln 2\quad\text{and therefore} \quad k=\frac{\ln 2}{h}.$$
Now use the given value $700\times 10^6$ of the half-life. I get that $k$ is approximately $9.902\times 10^{-10}$.

Comment: thank you very much :) it works for me as well

Comment: @André Nicolas I wish you to get well soon!

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Many thanks. Hospital stay just ended, path to recovery begins.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good to hear that.